# Need to apply a function to update a specific property of an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, function, mapping

I've got an array of clients coming in from an API and I need to format their "logo" in the controller before it hits the view. When I use `array_map` it's returning an array of just the formatted logos, but I need it to return the entire array with just the logo property for each entry being formatted.

It seems `array_map` and `array_walk` both return an array of only what has been formatted, but is there a function or some combination of functions that would return the original array with just updated values for a specific property?

Here's my current code, just basic `array_map` syntax. `clients_array` is an array of arrays that have a bunch of properties like name, location, logo, etc.:

```
    $clients_array = $this->clients->getClients();
    $clients_array = array_map(function ($logo) {
      return cloudfront_asset($logo->logo_thumbnail);
    }, $clients_array);
```

Comment: can you add current and expected array in your question for better understanding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You control the output of `array_map`, so instead of just returning the formatted logo, update your `$logo` object and return that.

```
$clients_array = $this->clients->getClients();
$clients_array = array_map(function ($logo) {
    $logo->logo_thumbnail_formatted = cloudfront_asset($logo->logo_thumbnail);
    return $logo;
}, $clients_array);
```